# runtime function target to multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, runtime, typeerror, python-multiprocessing

Is there a way to decide which function to run by the new process in run-time. (created by `multiprocessing.Process`)

Suppose I have 2 function

```
def f():
    print("In f")

def g():
    print("In g")

func_name = str(input("enter function to be run = "))

multiprocessing.Process(target = func_name, args = ()).start()
```

Now when I run the program

```
enter function to be run = f
```

This gives me error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This seems obvious because the name of the function should match, but in this case the name is in the variable `func_name` as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
functions = {'f': f, 'g': g}

multiprocess.Process(target=functions.get(func_name), args=()).start()
```

It would be better to make sure that `func_name` is actually in `functions`.  You could also have a default function that could be given as a second argument to `.get()`

Comment: I cannot actually do that. I do not in the beginning before writing the code how many functions there are, and their names. The user can give any number of functions with any names and ask the code to run them. Its like a wrapper for multiprocessing.Process.

Comment: @Haris: You *could* use `globals().get(func_name)` instead.